# css locator returns empty list

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy, selector

i am making a web scraping course on datacamp :D

in the session it self we are scraping datacamp websites to get courses names and urls
however,
i am trying to reach the same result on pycharm on my pc ,

unfortunately nothing happens

i have tried many css locators and the same result always empty list

can you just guide me what is the wrong ?

> from scrapy import Selector import requests
>
> url = 'https://www.datacamp.com/courses-all' html =
> requests.get(url).content sel = Selector ( text = html)
>
> courses_names =
> sel.css('section.css-6b6e9e-Search>article.css-1t5b87c-HitCard>h2.css-172ju3k-Box
> ::text').extract()
>
> print(courses_names)

Comment: If you are receiving an error or exception you should post it along with the full traceback. I am not certain that this is the cause of your problem, but I am pretty sure you are trying to feed a bytes object into the text parameter of the scrapy selector.

Comment: i got no error just empty cell ... as like the selector did not find anything even if i used this code boxes = sel.css('div ::text').extract()

Answer (score 0):

there isn't enough info so I will just explain what you are doing
from that CSS selector I can see, you are using a general selector

```
sel.css('section.css-6b6e9e-Search>article.css-1t5b87c-HitCard>h2.css-172ju3k-Box ::text').extract()
```

you shouldn't do that maybe because the website probably changes the class name every time

just, check if that selector is working on that website from the dev tools
and try to print the result of

```
sel.css('section > article').get()
```

it should print HTML tags if that selector is correct

hope you a good luck with web scraping

Comment: unfortunately i used this code
courses_names = sel.css('section > article').get() 
the result is NONE ... 
can i ask you weather this has any relation that the site is using java script ? 
i found some information says that but i even do not know how to handle it... 
some advised me to use selenium .. so what is your opinion ؟ 
and thank you so much

Comment: Assalamu alaikum first I thought that too but , you said you are following tutorial so I thought your teacher could get this data so you should get it too
but if the website has been updated yes that may be the problem